# Cron Job Not working with Python

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I made a script :

```
import os , time
from pathlib import Path
from pushover import Client
client = Client("MY CLIENT KEY", api_token="MY API KEY")

###Run aquatone
###Create a directory named site if not exists
###copy urls.txt in site directory
###Check for urls in urls.txt
domains = open('/root/programming/aquarecon/domains.txt', 'r')
hue = domains.readlines()
for site in hue:
        #run_aquatone = os.system('aquatone-discover -d ' + site.strip('\n') + ' -t 30')
        #run_aquatone_scan = os.system('aquatone-scan -d ' + site.strip('\n') + ' -t 30 -p huge')
        current_directory = os.getcwd()
        url_txt_path = '/root/aquatone/' + site.strip('\n') + '/urls.txt'
        #print(url_txt_path)
        site_directory = Path("/root/programming/aquarecon/"+ site.strip('\n'))
        time.sleep(1)
        if site_directory.is_dir() == False:
              print('Site Have Not Been Monitored Yet')
              os.system('mkdir '+ '' + '/root/programming/aquarecon/'+site.strip('\n'))
              copy_url_txt = os.system('cp '+ url_txt_path + ' ' + site.strip('\n') )
        else:
              print('Site Exists time to use flashback')
              open_new_urls = open('/root/aquatone/' + site.strip('\n') + '/urls.txt','r')
              open_old_urls = open('/root/programming/aquarecon/' +site.strip('\n') +'/urls.txt' , 'r')
              readlines_old = open_old_urls.readlines()
              readlines_new = open_new_urls.readlines()
              client.send_message('New Subdomain Found ', title="CRON")
              for i in readlines_new:
                  if i not in readlines_old:
                      client.send_message('New Subdomain Found ' + i, title="AquaRecon")
              copy_url_txt = os.system('cp '+ url_txt_path + ' ' +  site.strip('\n'))
```

and Even i set the cronjob as :

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /root/programming/aquarecon/aquarecon.py
```

But the script doesn't run anytime .
For a quick info:

Aquatone is a tool to enumerate subdomains :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Even tried doing */3 * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /root/programming/aquarecon/aquarecon.py

Answer (score 0):

I believe cron is based off of root, so when you call the pathlib, it is cron calling it, defaulting it to root.